# Separate HTML/Javascript code into

Tags: jquery, html, include, embed, external

I don't know what term for this is but it's like with PHP when you use 'includes' or when you store HTML in a variable and call it to print at a certain point in a HTML page.

I want to better organize and tidy up my html page which to me is so cluttered I'm getting brain fog just navigating my way around my code. I don't have a web server everything is running client side javascript. It's actually a HTA application.

I want for example to call a table that I've kept in a separate .html file into the Main html file.

so for example:

```
//main html file
<table>
<tr>
   <td>"call external html file here"</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

or if there is a way with jquery or javascript to store chunks of html code into a variable then call it to print in main html, although I don't know if this will take up too much resources. What are my options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To load external HTML, use JQuery `.load()` :
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Example:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

You can also separate your javascript into another file:

```
<script src="yourjavascript_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: is there a difference between this and $.get

Comment: @DanielHunter `$.get` uses an HTTP GET request.

Comment: Actually, `load()` is just a shortcut for `$.get` with the convience of loading the content right into an element.

Comment: They are both just shortcuts to `.ajax()`.

Comment: Yes they are, and $.ajax is a shortcut for XMLHttpRequest !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `load` function:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="load"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#load").load("http://link.to/file");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be templating, for starters: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Answer (score 0):

In the main html file, you can use code such as

```
next.body()
```

Then, in the file you want to call, you can use code such as

```
inherit file="base.html"
```

to call the main file.

But it all depends which framework you are using

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, the `load` function gives you great flexibility, not only can you insert a chunk of HTML, you can also insert only a select portion from that chunk by adding a space-separated selector expression after the link to HTML file:

```
$("#tobefilled").load("foo.html #onlythiselement",function() {});
```